# Paypal - Using Classic API for purchases and REST API for refunds

Tags: paypal

We're in the process of migrating to the PayPal REST APIs and have recently updated our refund process from the Classic API to the REST. We're a little hesitant to turn this on because we're still using the Classic API for purchase transactions. Will using the Classic API for purchases and the REST API for refunds cause any issues?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this will cause issues.  Only payments made with the REST API can be refunded via the REST API.  The REST API uses a different set of IDs for its data model which are not analogous/compatible with the IDs used by the classic APIs (at this point).

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#refund-a-sale - shows how the new REST APIs refund a sale, saleId are only available for payments made with the new REST API.